# JS use function inside function

Tags: javascript

I saw someone post this code:

```
function getFuncName() {
   return getFuncName.caller.name
}
```

Can someone plase explain what it means to use getFuncName inside the getFuncName function? Is there a reference for this in MDN web docs?

Comment: aparently is using a caller to obtain the name of the function that called it, however, using caller is deprecated and generally not recommended because it has limitations and potential security risks

Comment: "*what does it mean to use getFuncName inside the getFuncName function?*" - nothing special. You can refer to the function by `getFuncName` (and e.g. call it) both from outside and inside the function definition.

Comment: @ChrisG any reference for *"potential security risks"*?

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon If sensitive information is passed to a function, accessing its caller could expose this information to unauthorized code,also ppl could just use the caller to obfuscate code logic or hide malicious behavior.

Comment: @ChrisG yes that’s true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following statement is essentially: `window.getFuncName.caller.name`.

You are referencing the function by its (global) name, and requesting the name of the function that called it.

---

Using the [`caller`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller) property is not recommended. The same goes for the [`callee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee) property.

```js
function whoCalledMe() {
  return window.whoCalledMe.caller.name;
}

function iCalledYou() {
  console.log(whoCalledMe());
}

iCalledYou();
```

If you enable strictness, the code will actually error:

```js
'use strict';

function whoCalledMe() {
  return whoCalledMe.caller.name;
}

function iCalledYou() {
  console.log(whoCalledMe());
}

iCalledYou();
```

If you really wanted to do this safely, you should just create your own call stack... But why would you need to do this?

```js
const callStack = [];

function whoCalledMe() {
  return callStack.at(-1);
}

function iCalledYou() {
  callStack.push('iCalledYou'); // Push onto stack
  console.log(whoCalledMe());
  callStack.pop(); // Pop off stack
}

iCalledYou();
```

Comment: You should have answered the question IMO.

Comment: I would add that referring to a function from within the function is supported in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Here the getFuncName() function returns the name of the function that called it.

When you return getFuncName.caller.name you faced some issues
If you are looking to get the name of the function that called another function, you might need another Method.

**get the name of the function that is called getFuncName, you can pass the function itself as an argument**

```
function getCallerName(func) {     
         return func.name; 
}  
function myFunction() {     
   console.log(getCallerName(myFunction)); 
}  
 myFunction(); // Output: "myFunction"
```

Answer (score 0):

The docs are here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller

Definitely that's a legacy code and `caller` shouldn't be used in a new code.

To get a caller function name is sometimes needed, an error stack could be an altternative.
You can even get the function itself if you `eval()` its name and it's accessible from the current scope.

```js
'use strict';

function whoCalledMe() {
  try{
    throw new Error();  
  }catch(e){
    return e.stack.split('\n')[2].match(/\w+(?=\s*\()/)[0];
  }
}

function iCalledYou() {
  console.log(whoCalledMe());
}

iCalledYou();
```

Comment: You should have answered the question IMO.

Comment: I’m sorry to point this out but I have to: *"Can someone pl[e]ase explain what it means to use `getFuncName` inside the `getFuncName` function?"*

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon at least "Is there a reference for this in MDN web docs?" is answered which leads to other answers

Answer (score -2):

I hope this will answer your question-

So basically your code returns the caller function name -

```
function callerFunction(){ 

   console.log(getFuncName())

}
```

The output of the above code is "callerFunction".

Comment: You failed to answer the question. *"Can someone pl[e]ase explain what it means to use `getFuncName` inside the `getFuncName` function?"*?